# I am getting this error while running spyder from my base environment in anaconda prompt

Tags: anaconda, ide, spyder, navigator

```
(base) C:\Users\Lenovo>conda activate base

(base) C:\Users\Lenovo>spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 132, in main
    from spyder.config.manager import CONF
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spyder\config\manager.py", line 22, in <module>
    from spyder.config.main import CONF_VERSION, DEFAULTS, NAME_MAP
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spyder\config\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    from spyder.config.appearance import APPEARANCE
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spyder\config\appearance.py", line 15, in <module>
    from spyder.plugins.help.utils.sphinxify import CSS_PATH
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spyder\plugins\help\utils\sphinxify.py", line 37, in <module>
    from sphinx.application import Sphinx
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sphinx\application.py", line 35, in <module>
    from sphinx.registry import SphinxComponentRegistry
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sphinx\registry.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sphinx.builders import Builder
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sphinx\builders\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from sphinx.util import UnicodeDecodeErrorHandler, get_filetype, import_object, logging, rst
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sphinx\util\rst.py", line 16, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, pass_environment
ImportError: cannot import name 'pass_environment' from 'jinja2' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py)
```

I want my spyder IDE to be executed properly

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please remove this directory `C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python` and you'll be able to use Spyder again.